# After adding in Array element change oher element but not adding to array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i've got an array:

```
dataSet: [
{ name: "Имя1", image: "img.jpeg", author: "Александр Полтавченко", date: "21.02.2020", id: 1 },
      { name: "Имя2", image: "img.png", author: "Александр Полтавченко", date: "21.02.2020", id: 2 },
],
addedToCart: []
```

and here is the function which put value from `dataSet` to `addedToCart` according ID from props:

```
added =  (id) => {

  this.setState (( { addedToCart, dataList  } )=>{

  const newItem = dataList.filter(el=>el.id===id);
  const testArr = [...addedToCart ];
  const filteredATC = testArr.filter((item, el)=>{
    if(addedToCart.indexOf(item)===el){
      item.count++
     return item, el
  }
  else {
    return item
  }
```

it is works well (only one element with count ++) but if click add to another element it is just change element in array (with correct count surprisingly).
How to put another element into addedToCart, just like

```
[
{el1},
{el2}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

filter returns an array instead of the desired element, you should use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead.

I believe you would desire an approach like this:

```
added = (id) => {

  this.setState (( { addedToCart, dataList } ) => {

    const newItem = dataList.find(el=> el.id === id);
    const testArr = [...addedToCart ];
    const filteredATCIndex = testArr.findIndex((_item, id) => newItem.id === id)

    // if there is an added item
    if (filteredATCIndex !== -1) {
      const count = testArr[filteredATCIndex].count + 1
      testArr[filteredATCIndex] = { ...testArr[filteredATCIndex], count }
      return { addedToCart: testArr }
    }

    // for new item
    const newItemAdded = { ...newItem, count: 1 }
    testArr.push(newItemAdded)
    return { addedToCart: testArr }
  })
}
```

though this approach duplicates data, which is not desirable. I suggest you consider to change `addedToCart` to an object where *key* *value* pairs are the *id* and *count* respectively from added items. This way you would avoid duplicating data.

then your update state would look like:

```
added = (id) => {
  this.setState (( { addedToCart } ) => {
    const count = typeof addedToCart[id] === 'undefined' ? 1 : ++addedToCart[id]

    return { addedToCart: { ...addedToCart, [id]: count } }
  })
}
```